# Can't set different values for my TableColumn in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I tried to set a `Button` in a `TableView` column, but I didn't succeed in setting different buttons. It shows me the same buttons on all the columns.

The idea is that the name is set correctely, but my problem is when I set `cellValueFactory`. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaPatchuriPerBaza.length; i++) {

    if (listaPatchuriPerBaza[i].contains(".sql")) {
        k = i;
        pozitie = poz;
        Patch pt = new Patch(listaPatchuriPerBaza[i], "Run" + " " + listaPatchuriPerBaza[i]);
        listaPatchuri.add(pt);
        masterData.add(pt);
        patchColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patch, String>("denumire"));
        runColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patch, String>("btnText"));
        runColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Patch, String>, TableCell<Patch, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Patch, String> call(TableColumn<Patch, String> param) {

                Button btn = new Button(pt.getBtnText());

                //Set up the Table
                TableCell<Patch, String> cell = new TableCell<Patch, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            //actioneaza butonul de run
                            btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                                btn.setDisable(true);
                                Tooltip tool = new Tooltip("Running");
                                setTooltip(tool);
                                System.out.println("ruleaza");
                                try {
                                    SmbFile script = new SmbFile(path + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);

                                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {

                                    SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile(path + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);
                                    SmbFile smbToFile = new SmbFile(path + "Aplicate/" + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);
                                    smbFromFile.renameTo(smbToFile);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                            setGraphic(btn);

                        }
                    }

                };

                return cell;
            }
        });

    }

    tableView.setItems(masterData);

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the `for` loop here: are you trying to set the cell value factory and the cell factory once for each row in the table?

Comment: @James_D Yes i want to set for every element from my list, but i cant set the button. The names are ok.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The column only has one factory for the value and one factory for the cell. So you are just replacing them on each iteration of the loop. They are *factories*: i.e. they are called to create the objects as needed.

Comment: @James_D can you modify my code where i am wrong, please?

Comment: The correct way to take a screen capture in Windows is:  Hold down Alt and press the PrintScreen key once; press the Start button, type `paint`, press Enter;  when the Paint window appears, hold down Ctrl and type `v`;  then save the file (in PNG format, which should be the default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense to set the cell value factory and the cell factory once for each row in the table: all you do is replace the factory each time you iterate through your loop. These are *factories*: i.e. objects that create other objects. The table column will call their `call` methods as needed to create multiple cells etc.

So just set them once and update the button's text in the `updateItem()` method. The button needs to be a property of the *cell* (so that each cell has its own button, with its own text), not of the *cell factory* (because there is only one cell factory for the entire column).

```
runColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patch, String>("btnText"));
runColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Patch, String>() {
    Button btn = new Button();

    {
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Patch pt = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            btn.setDisable(true);
            Tooltip tool = new Tooltip("Running");
            setTooltip(tool);
            System.out.println("ruleaza");
            try {
                SmbFile script = new SmbFile(path + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile(path + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);
                SmbFile smbToFile = new SmbFile(path + "Aplicate/" + pt.getDenumire(), userCred);
                smbFromFile.renameTo(smbToFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            btn.setText(item);
            setGraphic(btn);
        }
    }
});
```